# Calculate and apply Git Tag for different Repo in Azure pipelines

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, semantic-versioning

Currently we have two repo one for Infra related and one for Source code. when I want to calculate its calculating against Infra branch because that's where its actually running. How can I calculate git version for a source code branch in different repo and apply? I am using Azure pipeline. currently its working for the Infra branch

Calculate tag

```
     - task: gitversion/setup@0
       displayName: Install GitVersion
       inputs:
        versionSpec: '5.x'

     - task: gitversion/execute@0
       displayName: Determine Version
       inputs:
         useConfigFile: true
         configFilePath: 'global/GitVersion.yml'
```

Apply Tag

```
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: | 
          git config --global user.email "$(Build.RequestedForEmail)"
          git config --global user.name "$(Build.RequestedFor)"
          if [ $(git tag -l "$(GitVersion.SemVer)") ]; then
            echo "Tag $(GitVersion.SemVer) already exists. Skipping Tagging."
          else
            git tag $(GitVersion.SemVer) -m "release build"
            git push origin $(GitVersion.SemVer) --force
          fi
```

****Update*****

based on this git https://github.com/GitTools/actions/issues/172 I can see we can set target branch, when I set I am getting warning and it picks dev as default.

*Multiple source branches have been found, picking the first one (dev).
This may result in incorrect commit counting.
Options were:
dev, release/1.0.1, releases/1.0.2, releases/1.0.0, main*

Comment: Can you specify your workflow and expectation please? You mentioned that you had 2 repos. Did you checkout the code from the two branches of the repos during pipeline run? Or, pipeline simply checks out the triggering/default branch of `self` repo. May I assume your pipeline is defined to checkout both the `Infra` branch of `Infra` repo and code from another branch in `Source code` repo? Can you share some insights on your current workflow to set tag and expecations?

Comment: sure. Current Flow: I checkout both Infra branch which has Docker file, others infra component like pipeline.yaml(Repo 1) and Source code branch (Repo 2). Expectation: When I run Git to calculate version or to add tag I want to calculate the version of source code repo/branch and add tag to that branch/repo. I hope I am clear.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your expectation and update, you may test with the sample below.

##### azure-pipelines.yml file in the `Infra` branch of `Infra` repo (`self`/`Repo1`)

```
trigger:
- Infra

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: Repo2
    name: SourceCode
    type: git

steps:
- checkout: self
  path: s/Repo1
  fetchDepth: 0
  persistCredentials: true

- checkout: Repo2
  path: s/Repo2
  fetchDepth: 0

- task: gitversion/setup@0
  displayName: Install GitVersion
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '5.x'

- task: gitversion/execute@0
  displayName: Determine Version
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s/Repo1'
    useConfigFile: true
    configFilePath: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s/Repo1/global/GitVersion.yml'

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "========== Show file structure in Agent.BuildDirectory =========="
      tree $(Agent.BuildDirectory)
      echo "GitVersion.SemVer is $(GitVersion.SemVer)"
      
      git config --global user.email "$(Build.RequestedForEmail)"
      git config --global user.name "$(Build.RequestedFor)"
      if [ $(git tag -l "$(GitVersion.SemVer)") ]; then
        echo "Tag $(GitVersion.SemVer) already exists. Skipping Tagging."
      else
        git tag $(GitVersion.SemVer) -m "release build"
        git push origin $(GitVersion.SemVer) --force
      fi
    workingDirectory: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s/Repo1/'
```

This pipeline first checks out the `self` repo (`Infra`) into the `s/Repo1` folder that is relative to the `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)`; then, similarly, it checks out the `Repo2` (`SourceCode`) into the `s/Repo2` folder; see [Checkout path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checkout-path);

[image]

Since the expectation is to tag `Infra` branch from Infra repo, the pipeline then executes `gitverion` with the `cofigFile` in

`$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s/Repo1/global/GitVersion.yml` and with targetPaht of `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s/Repo1`; this path is where the `Infra` repo is checked out.

Then with the help of git commands, the pipeline tags `infra` with `$(GitVersion.SemVer)`.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, currently I have a similar version except for setting the working directory while pushing the tag. but the problem is eventhough the version is calculated against source code branch but the naming conventions and others follow the Infra branch name. for e.g when I run the Infra feature branch against Dev branch. version is updated only when Dev branch is updated but *in gitversion.yml I mentioned if its dev branch use 'dev' in tag and for feature branch is to use feature branch name and currently it calculates the version but not with proper namings.

Comment: on further digging there is a open issue available to track. https://github.com/GitTools/actions/issues/798